# Error passing object using useHistory() in React.JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass an object as an argument using `useHistory()` but it won't seem to work for some reason. The idea is to click on either of the boxes as on the screenshot below which would then display the respective results(open, pending or closed) on a table in a different page. Although, right now it seems as if the object isn't getting passed on to the exact component responsible for displaying the table. The code snippets and the screenshots are as follows:

[image]

App.js

```
import ViewStatusData from "./screens/view_status_data/view_status_data";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainScreen}></Route>
          <Route path="/addData" component={AddDataScreen}></Route>
          <Route path="/tableData/:serial_number/:district/:ward/:category" component={TableData}></Route>
          <Route path="/editData/:serial_number" component={EditData}></Route>
          <Route path="/advanceFilter" component={AdvanceFilterScreen}></Route>
          <Route path="/viewAll" component={ViewAll}></Route>
          <Route path="/viewStatus/:status" component={ViewStatusData}></Route>  //The route in question
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code for the Status Boxes:

```
const StatusBox = () => {
    const [openStatus, setOpenStatus] = useState('');
    const [pendingStatus, setPendingStatus] = useState('');
    const [closedStatus, setClosedStatus] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    const openTickets = dummyData.flatMap(value => value.ward_no.flatMap(
        valueArray => ['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services'].flatMap(
            value => valueArray[value]))).filter(valueArray => valueArray.status === "open");

    useEffect(() => {
        setOpenStatus(openTickets)
    }, []);

    const pendingTickets = dummyData.flatMap(value => value.ward_no.flatMap(
        valueArray => ['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services'].flatMap(
            value => valueArray[value]))).filter(value => value.status === "pending");

    useEffect(() => {
        setPendingStatus(pendingTickets)
    }, []);

    const closedTickets = dummyData.flatMap(value => value.ward_no.flatMap(
        valueArray => ['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services'].flatMap(
            value => valueArray[value]))).filter(value => value.status === "closed");

    useEffect(() => {
        setClosedStatus(closedTickets)
    }, []);

    const clickedFunction = (value) => {          //The function that navigates to the page upon clicking either boxes
        console.log(value);                       //Console logging here displays the respective data that I intend to work with, the screenshot for which is below
        history.push(`/viewStatus/${value}`)
    }

    return (
        <div className="statusBoxes">
            <div className="openBox" onClick={() => clickedFunction(openStatus)}>
                <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px"}}>Open</div>
                <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px"}}>{openStatus.length}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="pendingBox" onClick={() => clickedFunction(pendingStatus)}>
                <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px"}}>Pending</div>
                <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px"}}>{pendingStatus.length}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="closedBox" onClick={() => clickedFunction(closedStatus)}>
                <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px"}}>Closed</div>
                <div style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px"}}>{closedStatus.length}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default StatusBox;
```

[image]

The ViewStatusData.jsx component(The component in charge of displaying the selected data on a table):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './view_status_data.css';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import StatusTable from "../../widgets/status_table/status_table";
import NavBar from "../../widgets/nav_bar/nav_bar";

const ViewStatusData = () => {
    const { status } = useParams();
    const [caseStatus, setCaseStatus] = useState(status);

    return (
        <div className="viewStatusData">
            <div className="viewStatusNavBar">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
            </div>
            <div className="statusCount">
                <StatusTable status={caseStatus}></StatusTable>    //This is the table 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ViewStatusData;
```

The StatusTable.jsx component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ImFilter } from 'react-icons/im';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const StatusTable = (props) => {
    const data = [];
    const history = useHistory();
    const [statusTable, setStatusTable] = useState(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        setStatusTable(props.status)
    }, [props.status]);

    console.log(props.status)     //Console logging here however, shows a different output screenshot for which is below

    const viewStatus = (value) => {
        history.push(`/editData/${value}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className="tableDataList">
            {!statusTable ? "No Data To Show" : <table className="serviceRequestList">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{ width: "5%" }}>Serial Number<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Name<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Date<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Issue<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Status<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                    </tr>
                    {statusTable.map((value, key) => (    //The line where the error gets thrown
                        <tr key={key} onClick={() => viewStatus(value.serial_number)}>
                            <td>{value.serial_number}</td>
                            <td>{value.name}</td>
                            <td>{value.date}</td>
                            <td>{value.issue}</td>
                            <td>{value.status}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default StatusTable;
```

The error I get says `TypeError: statusTable.map is not a function` which is the statusTable hook variable

Shows exactly the same number of `[object Object]` thingies as was on the box that was selected. The other thing is that this is logged thrice on the console. In this case, I had clicked on the Amber Box that holds the pending cases.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to pass an array of objects as a parameter via URL.
You should instead pass the parameter as a prop down to the `ViewStatusData` component and its child `StatusTable`.

Try to change the `StatusBox` JSX to display the `ViewStatusData`.
This view will display the data stored in a `status` case that will be updated by the `clickedFunction` method:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState([]);

const clickedFunction = (value) => {
  setStatus(value);
};

return (
<>
    <div className='statusBoxes'>
        <div className='openBox' onClick={() => clickedFunction(openStatus)}>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>Open</div>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>
            {openStatus.length}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='pendingBox' onClick={() => clickedFunction(pendingStatus)}>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>Pending</div>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>
            {pendingStatus.length}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='closedBox' onClick={() => clickedFunction(closedStatus)}>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>Closed</div>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>
            {closedStatus.length}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>;
    <div>
    <ViewStatusData caseStatus={status} />
</>
)
```

Then modify the `ViewStatusData` component to pass the `caseStatus` prop to its child:

```
const ViewStatusData = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="viewStatusData">
            <div className="viewStatusNavBar">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
            </div>
            <div className="statusCount">
                <StatusTable status={props.caseStatus}></StatusTable>  
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Of course, you won't need to declare a dedicated `/viewStatus/:status` route in your `App.js` file

Comment: I keep getting the same error. The error I get says TypeError: statusTable.map is not a function which is the statusTable hook variable. If you look at the StatusTable.jsx component, I have marked the line that throws the error

Comment: I still believe it has something to do with the object not getting passed in the right way